# How do i make my gtk app use the dark theme?

Tags: c, gtk, themes, gnome

Some apps on the gnome desktop like the image viewer use a dark variation of the theme.
What code is required to make my own gtk program use this dark variation of the theme?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the [`gtk-application-prefer-dark-theme`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.2/GtkSettings.html#GtkSettings--gtk-application-prefer-dark-theme) setting. This ought to do it:

```
g_object_set(gtk_settings_get_default(),
    "gtk-application-prefer-dark-theme", TRUE,
    NULL);
```

You may need to make sure you do it before you create any widgets.